# how to find if the process is suspended or not?

Tags: c++, process, suspend

i am using this code for suspend process.i found it here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/pausep.aspx

```
BOOL SuspendResumeThreadList(DWORD dwOwnerPID, bool bResumeThread) 
{ 
    HANDLE        hThreadSnap = NULL; 
    BOOL          bRet        = FALSE; 
    THREADENTRY32 te32        = {0}; 

    hThreadSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0); 
    if (hThreadSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        return (FALSE); 

    te32.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32); 

    if (Thread32First(hThreadSnap, &te32)) 
    { 
        do 
        { 
            if (te32.th32OwnerProcessID == dwOwnerPID) 
            {
                HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME, FALSE, te32.th32ThreadID);
                if (bResumeThread)
                {
                    //cout << _T("Resuming Thread 0x") << cout.setf( ios_base::hex ) << te32.th32ThreadID << '\n';
                    ResumeThread(hThread);
                }
                else
                {
                    //cout << _T("Suspending Thread 0x") << cout.setf( ios_base::hex ) << te32.th32ThreadID << '\n';
                    SuspendThread(hThread);
                }
                CloseHandle(hThread);
            } 
        }
        while (Thread32Next(hThreadSnap, &te32)); 
        bRet = TRUE; 
    } 
    else 
        bRet = FALSE;   
    CloseHandle (hThreadSnap); 
    return (bRet); 
}
```

Now i want a way to find if the process is suspended or not ???
please help me.

Comment: What do you mean "process is suspended"? Only threads can be suspended. You could define a process as suspended once all its threads are suspended - this also gives you a way how to detect it.

Comment: thanks,but how can i check if a thread is suspended or not???

Comment: There's not a documented API for doing that. If you need that sort of information you're going to have to examine the thread environment block, which is an implementation detail which can change on various versions of windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correct you can use [NtQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724509%28VS.85%29.aspx) for this purpose. With `NtQuerySystemInformation` you can get `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure by iterating over array of `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` and looking for the PID of the target process. You can find detailed description of `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` in Wine sources [here](http://source.winehq.org/source/include/winternl.h). After you get process information structure just look at `SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION` where you can check state of thread. For more details about structures and enums look at Wine sources.

Comment: Yup.  The only really reliable source of the declarations is in, of all places, the .NET framework.  NtProcessInfoHelper class.  Using the WMI Win32_Thread class takes the dependency out.  Take whatever you get with a major lump of salt, nothing more fickle then the thread state.  Can't freeze the operating system.

Comment: @Hans Passan: Thanks for pointing out NtProcessInfoHelper class. Didn't know about it, just examined with reflector.