# How to get the status of apps in Win8.1 task manager?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

Is there any way can I get the status of the apps in task manager?

[image: status of the apps in task manager]

**Edit:**
Actually,I'm trying to get the status of metro app on Win8.1, such us show "Running" or "Suspended" in task manager "Detail" label. 
I tried to use GetProcess() to get all the current process then get its' threads state. But the result is different from what task manager show.

Could any give me a gelp? I'm now using C# or C++ to coding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find if the process is suspended or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510534/how-to-find-if-the-process-is-suspended-or-not)

Comment: You want to do it in c# or c++? Also what are the values you're interested in? Running, Suspended, Not Responding. Anything else? There is no API for getting this value AFAIK, you need to find it yourself.

Comment: I already update my question! Thanks !

Comment: This has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50172564/detect-suspended-windows-8-10-process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for hundreds times, I change my way to think "How to get info from task manager?"

So I think I just need to get info from task manager in command prompt.

There is a command I set:

```
tasklist /apps /fi "STATUS eq SUSPENDED"
```

There will show the metro apps name in SUSPENDED state!!!