# Detect "suspended" Windows 8/10 process

Tags: windows, api, winapi, uwp, power-management

UWP (or "Metro") apps in Windows 8/10 can be suspended when they are not in the foreground. Apps in this state continue to exist but no longer consume CPU time. It looks like this change was introduced to improve performance on low-power/storage devices like tablets and phones.

What is the most elegant and simple method to detect a process in this state?

I can see 2 possible solutions at the moment:

1. Call NtQuerySystemInformation() and the enumerate each process and each thread. A process is "suspended" if all threads are in the suspended state. This approach will require a lot of code and critically NtQuerySystemInformation() is only semi-documented and could be removed in a future OS. NtQueryInformationProcess() may also offer a similar solution with the same problem.
2. Call GetProcessTimes() and record the counters for each process. Wait some longish time (minutes) and check again. If the process counters haven't changed then assume the process is suspended. I admit this is a hack but maybe could work if the time period is long enough.

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Assuming that you can determine this state, what are you going to do with that information?

Comment: I maintain an enterprise app that performs system maintenance tasks. Tasks can be postponed whilst other "important" programs are running. Windows 8/10 changes this because UWP programs now enter the suspended state and stay there for a long time. It is therefore now necessary to differentiate long suspended programs from live running processes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for this exist [`PROCESS_EXTENDED_BASIC_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt809132(v=vs.85).aspx) - meaning of flags in it described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47347441/6401656). you are need `IsFrozen` flag. so you need open process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access (for do this for all processes, you will be need have `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` enabled in token). and call `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `ProcessBasicInformation` and [`PROCESS_EXTENDED_BASIC_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt809132(v=vs.85).aspx) as input. for enumerate all processes we can use `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemProcessInformation`. of course possible and use `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` + `Process32First` + `Process32Next` but this api very not efficient, compare direct call to `NtQuerySystemInformation`

also possible enumerate all threads in process and check it state and if state wait - wait reason. this is very easy, because all this information already returned by single call to `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemProcessInformation`. with this we not need open processes. usually both this ways give the same result (for suspended/frozen) processes, but however use `IsFrozen` is most correct solution.

```
void PrintSuspended()
{
    BOOLEAN b;
    RtlAdjustPrivilege(SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE, TRUE, FALSE, &b);

    ULONG cb = 0x1000;
    NTSTATUS status;
    do 
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

        if (PBYTE buf = new BYTE[cb])
        {
            if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
            {
                union {
                    PBYTE pb;
                    SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION* spi;
                };

                pb = buf;

                ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;
                do 
                {
                    pb += NextEntryOffset;

                    if (!spi->UniqueProcessId)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, 
                        (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR)spi->UniqueProcessId))
                    {
                        PROCESS_EXTENDED_BASIC_INFORMATION pebi;
                        if (0 <= NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, &pebi, sizeof(pebi), 0) &&
                            pebi.Size >= sizeof(pebi))
                        {
                            if (pebi.IsFrozen)
                            {
                                DbgPrint("f:%x %wZ\n", spi->UniqueProcessId, spi->ImageName);
                            }
                        }
                        CloseHandle(hProcess);
                    }

                    if (ULONG NumberOfThreads = spi->NumberOfThreads)
                    {
                        SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION* TH = spi->TH;
                        do 
                        {
                            if (TH->ThreadState != StateWait || TH->WaitReason != Suspended)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        } while (TH++, --NumberOfThreads);

                        if (!NumberOfThreads)
                        {
                            DbgPrint("s:%x %wZ\n", spi->UniqueProcessId, spi->ImageName);
                        }
                    }

                } while (NextEntryOffset = spi->NextEntryOffset);
            }
            delete [] buf;
        }
    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try both of these approaches. It is a shame both need SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE but not a problem for my application.

Comment: @jimc - `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` enabled you needonly if you want open all processes (including protected system processes). however have it is optional - you simply got access denied when try open some processes.

Comment: I would just like to note that `IsFrozen` does not work for normal processes, only UWP (at least according to my tests).

Comment: @MiroslavPolicki any process suspended under debugger also `IsFrozen`

Comment: @RbMm Interesting. I used `NtSuspendProcess` though.

Comment: @MiroslavPolicki - no, `NtSuspendProcess` not give such effect. but when debug event was in process and debugger attached to it - system before call debugger - exactly frozen process. not suspend but frozen.