# Window is invisible, but IsWindow + IsWindowVisible + IsWindowEnabled return true and GetWindowRect returns plausible values

Tags: windows, api

I'm iterating through all windows on the Windows desktop in order to allow disable patients select them easily in order to type into them.

I get all windows using

```
hw = GetDesktopWindow()
' It's first child is the 1st top level window
hw = GetWindow(hw, GW_CHILD)

'Now loop through all windows
```

etc.

There are many windows which are invisible or disabled, and I simply skip them because the user should not be able to select them. He wouldn't be able to type into them anyway.

Now I am confronted with a strange window.

Its title is "Groove Music".
It's a window from the Window Groove music app, and I can see it in the taskmanager.

[image]

I use the following API calls to check if this is a valid window that the user should be able to select:

```
IsWindow
IsWindowEnabled
IsWindowVisible
```

The declarations of these API calls are 100% perfect, I use them since years already.

And last, I even check its GetWindowRect values to see if it's in the screen at all.

And then I even check if it's a layered window (like an overlay that some apps use for non-clickable messages):

```
Public Function IsWindowLayered(ByVal uHwnd As Long) As Boolean

    Dim lret&
    lret = GetWindowLong(uHwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)

    If (lret And WS_EX_LAYERED) = WS_EX_LAYERED Then
        IsWindowLayered = True
    End If

End Function
```

It returns false.

The funny thing how is that the window is actually invisible.
So the user should not be able to select it.

Which function may I have missed to check if the window is actually visible?

Thank you!

Edit: It's also the calculator window (calc.exe) after I had opened it and closed it again.

Edit 2:
I also check for WS_VISIBLE like that, but even that return true for that window:

```
Public Function IsWindowVisibleEx(ByVal uHwnd As Long) As Boolean

    Dim lret&
    lret = GetWindowLong(uHwnd, GWL_STYLE)
    
    If (lret And WS_VISIBLE) = WS_VISIBLE Then
        IsWindowVisibleEx = True
    End If

End Function
```

Edit 3: The taskmanager says that Calculator.exe and Groove have the status "Suspended".

Comment: "I can see it in the taskbar" => This is strong evidence that the window is in fact visible.

Comment: @BenVoigt It says "Stopped". I will add a screenshot.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sorry, I wanted to write "Taskmanager". Spello improved and screenshot added.

Comment: That is something completely different from "invisible", as you have already been told by `IsWindowVisible`

Comment: If the program is stuck in an infinite loop and can't process window messages, it won't be able to paint itself as necessary.

Comment: @MarkRansom The taskmanager says that Calculator.exe and Groove have the status "Suspended".

Comment: I think this is related to being Modern UI Apps, not USER32.dll windows.

Comment: @tmighty: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform_apps

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50172564/103167